# Rest API best practice - list possible values of entity attribute

Tags: java, angular, api, rest, dropdown

To determine how to return data to fill in dropdown lists in UI, and to determine the best practice in rest uri to support this.

Suppose you have an entity Car which has an attribute "type".

This type attribute can be one of the following values

```
{ code : CPE, label : "Coupe"}
{ code : SPT, label : "Sports"}
{ code : LUX, label : "Luxury"}
```

In your api, you have **/api/cars** for which the get http request returns all cars

The question is , what is the best practice to return the list of possible car types and their labels (which could be internationalized).

What would the uri be for this ?

Would you create a /api/cartypes uri ? Then you will have tons of uri's for all the dropdowns in your application.

If you allow to return the cartypes under the cars ressource.. what would the uri be ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you return a List of Car objects and your URI looks like api/Cars

From what you describe it sounds like one URI for the REST call then you handle the info however you want on the caller side. To have each dropdown make a REST call each time it is selected seems highly inefficient for a problem that appears to not require it, however it could be done. If you MUST do it that way you have a click action make the call to an api and each dropdown links to its own resource (that has a getter that returns a list of whatever it is you are looking for).

Another option here is to use one URI and use an implementation of polling / long polling to update the List of Cars. But again - not very efficient. For this type of info I would just call once when the page loads and then populate off of that